# VUEJS import js file ERROR Failed to compile with 6 errors These relative modules were not found: * ../layout-mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vue.js, import

ERROR  Failed to compile with 6 errors
These relative modules were not found:

- ../layout-mode in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js
- ./item in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js
- ./layout-mode in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js
- ./layout-modes/fit-rows in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js
- ./layout-modes/masonry in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js
- ./layout-modes/vertical in ./src/assets/js/autoptimize.js

```
  <div id="app">
    <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    <main>
      <fade-transition origin="center" mode="out-in" :duration="250">
        <router-view />
      </fade-transition>
    </main>
    <router-view name="footer"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
  @import './assets/css/autoptimize.css';
  @import './assets/css/style.css';
  @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i|Cormorant+Garamond:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,100i,200i,300i,400i,500i,600i,700i,800i,900i&#038;subset=latin';
  @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400%7CPoppins:700%2C400';
</style>

<script>
import { FadeTransition } from "vue2-transitions";
import { analytics } from "./assets/js/analytics";
import { generator } from "./assets/js/generator";
import { javelin } from "./assets/js/javelin";
import { javelin2 } from "./assets/js/javelin2";
import { javelintop } from "./assets/js/javelintop";
import { jquery } from "./assets/js/jquery";
import { revslider } from "./assets/js/revslider";
import { autoptimize } from "./assets/js/autoptimize";

export default {
  components: {
    FadeTransition,
    javelintop, 
    jquery, 
    analytics, 
    generator, 
    revslider, 
    javelin2, 
    javelin,
    autoptimize
  }
};
</script>
```

I can't fix this error ...

Comment: Seems like you're trying to import normal JavaScript files. Any module you're trying to import should have a ```module.exports``` or ```export default``` statement.

Comment: I try that but my error is already here